# Use of operator overloading in structure within class

Tags: c++

I have a header file where i am declaring a class with a structure within it. Also i am declaring an overloading operator(!=, to compare structures) as member of this class. I am giving the definition of this operator in the cpp file. But i am not able to access the members of the structure

car.h

```
class car
{ 
int carsor;

struct model
{
    int id;

    int mode;

}prev,curr;

bool operator !=(const model& model1);

};
```

car.cpp

```
#include "car.h"

bool car::operator !=(const model& model1)
{
if((model1.id==model.id)&&(model1.mode==model.mode))
{
    return false;
}

else
{

    return false;
}
}
```

The error i get is this

```
Error   2   error C2275: 'car::model' : illegal use of this type as an expression
```

how should i access the the structure members?

Comment: Do you want to compare a `car` with a `model`, or `model`s between themselves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if((model1.id==model.id)&&(model1.mode==model.mode))` - `model` is the name of your class and not your object. Your object is accessible via `this` or you may omit it altogether inside the class.
Use `if((model1.id==prev.id)&&(model1.mode==prev.mode))` to compare with `prev` or `if((model1.id==next.id)&&(model1.mode==next.mode))` to compare with next.

Comment: this->id cannot be used here since through it i will be able to access only members of the class, not members of the structure. Omitting altogether also gives an 'undeclared identifier' error :(

Comment: Well, here it compiles just fine: http://liveworkspace.org/code/819648d58e562eb1310b09519fdef342

Comment: Thats because you are using the structure objcets prev and current. Suppose i want to use this in a totally different cpp file where i create an instance of the class and 2 structures of type model. and then i do "if(model1 !=model2) ....here i wont be knowing prev and curr....i just have 2 structures of the type model...

Comment: @user1783299 you have to decide what do you want to compare. The operator as you defined it belongs to class car and you want to compare models. You need to move it inside the model struct in your header file and change the definition of the operator in cpp file: `bool car::model::operator !=(const model& model1)`

Comment: ok thanks. The problem was i had to make this structure a protected member of the class so moving the operator overloading within the structure would make it inaccessible. So wanted to keep it as a member of class in public. That doesnt seem correct. Any way out?

Comment: It would make it inaccessible only if you try to invoke your operator outside the scope of `car` class or its derivatives. If that's what you're trying to do, there is something wrong with your design.

Comment: ok.. thanks a lot for the help :) ...i think it should be accessible since the other class is a derivative :)

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
bool car::operator !=(const model& model1)
{
```

is a method comparing a car to a model. This, however:

```
bool car::model::operator != (car::model const &other) const
{
  return !(*this == other);
}
```

is a method comparing two models (I've written it here as a method of `car::model`, but it could be a free function if you prefer.

I've also written it in terms of `operator==`, because the logic almost always works out easier:

```
bool car::model::operator ==(car::model const &other) const
{
    return (this->id == other.id) && (this->mode == other.mode);
}
```

These methods would be declared as:

```
class car
{ 
    struct model
    {
        int id;
        int mode;
        bool operator==(model const&) const;
        bool operator!=(model const&) const;
        // ...
```

Comment: so i cannot have it within the class as a member and still use it compare 2 structures?

Comment: you can *also* have an operator that compares a car to a model, if that's what you mean? But that isn't what you asked for ...

Comment: no i want to compare two models only. The problem was i had to make this structure a protected member of the class so moving the operator overloading within the structure would make it inaccessible in some other cpp file. So wanted to keep it as a member of class in public. That doesnt seem correct. Any way out?

Comment: How can code that doesn't have access to a protected `car::model` compare two of them in the first place?

Comment: okay :) ...i have a class that derives from this.  will I be able to access the "!=" operator in that derived class if i make the structure car::model protected?